# Moving list of item of different objects

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

> Hi guys, I am a real noob and a layman. I need help on how to copy items from booking to bookinghist.
>   Say that I have the Java class with partially different fields.  How can this be done?

```
List<Booking> booking= new ArrayList<Booking>();
List<BookingHist> bookinghist = new ArrayList<BookingHist>();
```

This is the Booking class below.
Here, the only different fields between the two classes is that BookingHist has a "extras"  column.

```
public class Booking implements Serializable {

        @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        @Column(name = "dt")
        private Date dt = new Date();
        @Column(name = "bookingname")
        private String bookingname;

        public Booking(Date dt, String bookingname) {

            this.dt=dt;
            this.bookingname=bookingname;              
        }

        public Date getDt() {
            return Dt;
        }

        public void setDt(Date Dt) {
            this.Dt = Dt;
        }

        public String getBookingname() {
            return Bookingname;
        }

        public void setBookingname(String Bookingname) {
            this.Bookingname = Bookingname;
        }
    }
```

This is the BookingHist class.

```
public class BookingHist implements Serializable {

        @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        @Column(name = "dt")
        private Date dt = new Date();
        @Column(name = "bookingname")
        private String bookingname;
        @Column(name = "createdDt")
        private Date createdDt;

        public BookingHist(Date dt, String bookingname, Date createdDt) {

            this.dt=dt;
            this.bookingname=bookingname;
            this.createdDt=createdDt;
        }

        public Date getDt() {
            return Dt;
        }

        public void setDt(Date Dt) {
            this.Dt = Dt;
        }

        public String getBookingname() {
            return Bookingname;
        }

        public void setBookingname(String Bookingname) {
            this.Bookingname = Bookingname;
        }

        public Date getCreatedDt() {
            return createdDt;
        }

        public void setCreatedDt(Date createdDt) {
            this.createdDt = createdDt;
        }

    }
```

Comment: what value you want to set for `extras` field in `BookingHist`?

Comment: Actually to be specific I would add a Date createdDt instead of String extras. The value would be the current date so I will get new Date()

Comment: basically you need to write a mapper. So one simple solution you can write is write a constructor like `BookingHist(Booking booking,String value){this.dt=booking.dt; this.bookingname=booking.name; this.extra=value}` will do job for you and inside map construct it like `map(t-> new BookingHist(t,someValue)` like @Deadpool mentioned

Comment: In actual fact, I have a lot of fields in both the Booking and BookingHist class. Would it be a good way to add constructor with many fields? and it would mean I have to put all the fields in .map()? Or is there another better way?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the all args constructor in `BookingHist` like below

```
public BookingHist(Date dt, String bookingname, String extras) {

     this.dt=dt;
     this.bookingname=bookingname;
     this.extras=extras;
 }
```

Then you can convert `Booking` to `BookingHist` by using stream

```
List<BookingHist> bookinghist = booking.stream()
                                       .map(b-> new BookingHist(b.getDate(), b.getBookingname(), "extra value");
                                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Sorry, I totally forgot about the constructor,, so I am editing it. But anyway, in actual fact, I have a lot of fields in both the Booking and BookingHist class. Would it mean I have to put all the fields in .map()?  Or is there another better way?

Comment: Actually I just realized that I do not have a constructor so I cannot do it this way

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using MapStruct
[MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org/)

Check out an example [Example map Entity to Dto](https://medium.com/@tushar.sharma118/mapstruct-an-exploratory-example-51047d97352d)